# Composer global require Laravel/Installer not working on Ubuntu

Tags: php, linux, laravel, ubuntu, composer-php

I'm trying to run `composer global require "laravel/installer"` on my Ubuntu machine (Trenta OS Distro) and for some reason I can't get it to install.

> file_put_contents(./composer.json): failed to open stream: Permission denied

I get the error above on every attempt. I've been unable to find any help on google so I'm guessing this isn't a very common problem. I tried  `whereis` command on that file and it gives me a location

```
/usr/local/bin/composer
```

I tried running `chmod -R 777` on that file but it did nothing. I don't know what else to do.

Composer was installed on my machine with the following command

```
curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | sudo php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer
```

I thought `composer.json` only comes with projects, but I shouldn't need an existing project in order to simply set up the Laravel Installer right?

Comment: run [ sudo composer global require "laravel/installer" ]

Comment: Lol that was it, my bad, thank you :)

Comment: if u run as Sudo - Running composer as root/super user is highly discouraged as packages, plugins and scripts cannot always be trusted

Comment: I was able to solve this by follow this answes https://askubuntu.com/questions/925072/unable-to-execute-the-laravel-command-laravel-new-myapp/925139#925139?newreg=37996f817d18405aaed0977f51ebc914

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I had the same problem and after reading this [answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/597738/running-composer-without-using-sudo-tried-changed-owner-and-permissions) I solved it updating the `.composer` folder permissions:

```
sudo chown -R $USER:$USER /home/$USER/.composer
```

Where `$USER` is your machine's username.

Update: As @Lucas Bustamante pointed, you don't need to change $USER for your username, its an environment variable already.

As [Ian Warner](https://stackoverflow.com/users/973192/ian-warner) commented out, is not a good idea to run composer as sudo user, because it can lead to security issues.

Comment: plus(1) for useful info.

Comment: PS: $USER is a system variable for the current logged-in user. You don't need to change that if you want to assign ownership to your current user.

Comment: When I run this I get: chown: mypcusername: illegal group name

Answer (score 0):

```
usr/local/bin/composer composer global require "laravel/installer"

usr/local/bin/composer composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel myblog
```

Comment: A good answer usually includes some explanation. Please, add one.

Answer (score 0):

I think this may solve your problem as it did for me.

I made a bash file for the whole process of global installation of Laravel.
[download it from here](https://gist.github.com/arvinismaili/73283bc73536e79fc6f47ec16708eab5), open a terminal in the bash file directory and run the command below:

```
bash Laravel_Global_Installer.sh
```

This bash file manages installations of:

1. Latest version of PHP and its extensions
2. Latest version of Composer (Global)
3. Latest version of Laravel (Global)

This will help you install Composer Globally and without sudo. Therefore you will be able to install Laravel Globally.

Answer (score 0):

first run `whereis composer` then
navigate to the that directory and run
sudo chown -R $USER:$USER / composer

Answer (score -2):

use sudo before the command,

for e.g.: sudo composer global require "laravel/installer"

Comment: Your answer is a repeat of an earlier comment